# Node export to excel

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im having a very hard time doing the simple task of writing an array of numbers to an excel file.

I tried:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path + "file.xls");

for (var x = 0; x < dataArr.length; x++) {
    // convert to string
    writeStream.write('' + dataArr[x]);
}

writeStream.close();
```

However, this just keeps writing the array values to the same row. So in the end, theres only one row with the last value. How is it possible to create a new row each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, try:

```
writeStream.write('' + dataArr[x] + '\n');
```